# how to jump to a specific part of a pdf using \hyperref or something else

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to make a reference to a previous example in my paper. How can i make a reference that takes you to the related example when clicked on? I am a very amateur user so I need it to be as simple as possible.
My goal is:
say that we are on example 4.4.3 . I wanna say "using the set given in example 2.2.2" and let the reader go to example 4.4.3 by clicking on it.

Comment: add a \label in example 2.2.2 and then \ref will work.

Comment: that only gives the name, but doesn't go there when you click on it

Comment: it should if you load hyperref. If not, show a small complete example that can be used for test.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
    \begin{example}[First example]\label{ex:first}
        Content.
    \end{example}
    \begin{example}[Second example]
        Using the set given in Example~\ref{ex:first}\ldots
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

Taking a look at the `cleveref` package might be beneficial.